# Отношения пояснения и уточнения

Tags: уточнения

Как отличить пояснение от уточнения?

> Этот, дорогой для меня (?) человек теперь уходит...

Этот = дорогой для меня?

Этот (какой именно) дорогой для меня?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Между **двумя определениями** в общем случае возможны однородные, неоднородные и пояснительные/уточняющие отношения, что соответствует **разной пунктуации**: запятая, нет запятой, две запятые.

В приведенном предложении первое определение является **местоименным**, и можно предположить следующие варианты:

(1) **Нет знака**, неоднородные отношения: ***Этот дорогой** для меня человек теперь уходит...*

(2) **Обособление**, уточняющие отношения: ***Этот, дорогой** для меня, человек теперь уходит...*

(3) **Ставится запятая**, пояснительные определения однородного вида: ***Этот, дорогой** для меня человек теперь уходит...*

2. У Розенталя допускаются **два первых варианта:**

**[Розенталь, пункт 4](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=118#pp118).**  Уточняющие определения могут конкретизировать общее значение местоимений этот, тот, такой, каждый, один (в значении местоимения) и т. п.: Хотелось отличиться перед **этим, дорогим для меня**, человеком (М. Г.); Затем удивила Дашу «доморощенность» всего этого, так нашумевшего, дерзновения (А. Т.);

Но если определительный оборот, стоящий после указательного местоимения, **тесно примыкает** к нему и не имеет значения уточнения, то он **не отделяется** запятой от этого местоимения: **Эти недавно построенные** дома уже полностью заселены.

Третьего варианта в правилах для местоимения ***этот*** нет. Вероятно, такие отношения возможны **не для всех** местоимений. Но тем не менее при том оформлении можно сослаться на это **правило**.

**[Розенталь, примечание к пункту 2](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=119#pp119).** Определения, носящие характер пояснения (перед ними можно поставить слова а именно, то есть и т. п.), **отделяются запятой** от поясняемого слова, но после них запятая не ставится:  Он заговорил совсем **другим,  серьёзным** тоном.

3. **ВЫВОД**

Выбираем вариант с обособлением: **Этот, дорогой** для меня, человек теперь уходит...

Comment: Sharon, у вас именно так задумано – *человек* тоже входит в обособление?

Comment: Спасибо, нет. Он туда случайно попал. В примере у Розенталя человека нет. Извините.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но я не поняла: выбирает отношения читающий (пишущий)? Потому возможно считать это и пояснением, и уточнением?

Comment: Если текст написан, то мы объясняем выбор автора. Если вы сами пишете, то вы делаете выбор.  Я бы выбрала вариант с обособлением: он более всего подходит к этому предложению и его можно объяснить по ссылке на Розенталя.  Это правило для уточнения. А однородное пояснение  вряд ли подходит. Терминология по Розенталю.

Comment: Поняла. Спасибою